# How can I make text bold in google hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

I am using hangouts, and would like to know how can I make message text bold.

I tried using markdown by adding * before and after words, but it didn't work. I get asterisks displayed next to the words. when I try this `*Hello*` I get this: `*Hello*` rather then this: **Hello**

Note:
I'm using google hangouts, not google chat.

Comment: Are you writing it as `* bold word *` (spaces between the * and the word) or `*bold word*` (no spaces)?

Comment: @Mokubai, no spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been asking around and turns out that for google hangouts in gmail on the web `ctrl+b` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the official answer [by Google Support](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/7649118?hl=en) says adding *'s should work, along with all the other formatting options for text that you can choose from:

> To bold text, add asterisks * before and after the text you want bolded.
> For example, if you type *Tuesday*, the chat will display **Tuesday**.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Do any of the other formatting options in that article work for you? When you say "it doesn't work", does it just display the asterisks * next to the word?

Comment: I can't open google support currently. (Microsoft family features), and yes it just displays asterisks next to the word. (by the way we're talking about _hangouts_ not google chat)